# Undefined property: stdClass::$collapsible

Tags: 7, installation-profiles, forms

After creating a vertical tab in my installation profile I keep getting these notices:

`Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$collapsible in field_group_pre_render_tab()`

and

`Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$collapsed in field_group_pre_render_tab()`

Here is the code I use to make a vertical tab in my installation profile:

```
$verticalTab = new stdClass();
$verticalTab->disabled = FALSE;
$verticalTab->identifier = 'group_attachments|node|foo|form';
$verticalTab->group_name = 'group_attachments';
$verticalTab->entity_type = 'node';
$verticalTab->bundle = 'foo';
$verticalTab->mode = 'form';
$verticalTab->label = 'Attachments';
$verticalTab->children = array( 1 => 'attachment');
$verticalTab->format_type = 'tab';
$verticalTab->weight = '0';
```

So am I missing something? or has this notice got nothing to do with the vertical tab and do I have to look elsewhere?

Any help to fix this notice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the `collapsed` and `collapsible` properties are used on [fieldsets](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#collapsible).
It looks like `field_group` is expecting for an undefined property on the vertical tabs object.

You could try adding them to your definition as such:

```
$verticalTab->collapsible = FALSE;
$verticalTab->collapsed = FALSE;
```

That should keep the `field_group` module happy.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, unfortunately this didn't solve my problem. In my vertical tab I have a 'file upload' field. Once I select an image and press upload, that is the moment the notices appear. Could the attachment field be the problem?